# js promise. Последовательная проверка на наличие элементов через промисы

Tags: javascript

Нужно что бы проверка шла вначале на hello, если hello появилось пошла проверка на World, если на World прошла идет проверка на Button.Почему у меня всё сразу проверяется ?

```js
const hello = '<p id="idHello">hello</p>'
const world = '<p id="idWorld">world</p>'
const button = '<button id="idButton" onclick="showanything()"> BUTTON </button>'

let showanything = function showanything() {
  alert('Вы нажали на кнопку');
}

setTimeout(() => {
  document.write(hello);
}, 2000);

setTimeout(() => {
  document.write(world);
}, 4000);

setTimeout(() => {
  document.write(button);
}, 6000);

let timerFunc = function(element_id) {
  let timerId = setInterval(() => {
    if (document.getElementById(element_id)) {
      console.log(`${element_id} exist`);
      clearInterval(timerId);
      clearTimeout(stopTimer);
      return element_id
    } else {
      console.log(`${element_id} does not exist`);
    }
  }, 1000)
  let stopTimer = setTimeout(() => {
    clearInterval(timerId);
    console.log('timeout');
  }, 10000);
}


var request1 = timerFunc('idHello');
var request2 = timerFunc('idWorld');

Promise.all([request1, request2]).then(function() {
  console.log('da')
});
```

Comment: `timerFunc` не возвращает `Promise` - поэтому смысла в строчке `Promise.all` нет

Comment: на примере всё работает вроде не?

Comment: Скрипт проверяет всё сразу, то есть он за 10 секунд проверяет сразу все элементы, а нужно что бы на каждую проверку уделял 10 секунд и в течении этих 10 секунд он проверял только один нужный элемент

Answer (score 0):

[`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) переходит в состояние resolved, когда все `Promise`, переданные в аргументах, перешли в состояние resolved.

В данном случае передается массив состоящий из `undefined`, как следствие, `Promise.all` разрешается сразу.

Для решения достаточно, чтобы `timerFunc` возвращал `Promise`, например так

```
let timerFunc = function(element_id) {
  return new Promise(r => {
    let timerId = setInterval(() => {
      if (document.getElementById(element_id)) {
        console.log(`${element_id} exist`);
        clearInterval(timerId);
        clearTimeout(stopTimer);
        r(element_id)
      } else {
        console.log(`${element_id} does not exist`);
      }
    }, 1000)
    let stopTimer = setTimeout(() => {
      clearInterval(timerId);
      console.log('timeout');
      r('timeout');
    }, 10000);
  });
}
```

```js
const hello = '<p id="idHello">hello</p>'
const world = '<p id="idWorld">world</p>'
const button = '<button id="idButton" onclick="showanything()"> BUTTON </button>'

let showanything = function showanything() {
  alert('Вы нажали на кнопку');
}

setTimeout(() => {
  document.write(hello);
}, 2000);

setTimeout(() => {
  document.write(world);
}, 4000);

setTimeout(() => {
  document.write(button);
}, 6000);

let timerFunc = function(element_id) {
  return new Promise(r => {
    let timerId = setInterval(() => {
      if (document.getElementById(element_id)) {
        console.log(`${element_id} exist`);
        clearInterval(timerId);
        clearTimeout(stopTimer);
        r(element_id)
      } else {
        console.log(`${element_id} does not exist`);
      }
    }, 1000)
    let stopTimer = setTimeout(() => {
      clearInterval(timerId);
      console.log('timeout');
      r('timeout');
    }, 10000);
  });
}


var request1 = timerFunc('idHello');
var request2 = timerFunc('idWorld');

Promise.all([request1, request2]).then(function() {
  console.log('da')
});
```